# Entries delete from knockout ui, but not from db

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, ninject

I use WebApi in MVC 4 with EF, Ninject.
In client i use knockout.js end it's delete my entries from UI, but it's still in DB.
Add, update action works fine.

Client code:

```
 self.removeUser = function (user) {
              var conj = ko.toJS(user);
              var json = JSON.stringify(conj);
              var Id = user.Id();
              $.ajax({
                  url: API_URL + Id,
                  cache: false,
                  type: 'DELETE',
                  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                  data: '',
                  success: function () {
                      self.Users.remove(user);
                  }
              });
          }
```

WebAPI

```
 // DELETE api/user/5
public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
{
    _userRepository.Delete(id);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

Repository

```
  public void Delete(int userId)
    {
        var user = Get(userId);
        _db.Users.Remove(user);
    }
```

Where to start? Which way to go?

Comment: Where do you call `_db.SaveChanges()` after your Delete?

Comment: It was too long and sleepless night. Thank you. You can post it as an answer =))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delete an entity is is not enough to remove it form its collection. You need to call `DbContext.SaveChanges()` in order to commit the transaction and persist your changes into the DB:

```
public void Delete(int userId)
{
    var user = Get(userId);
    _db.Users.Remove(user);
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```